# How to push same documents in top an array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, mean-stack, meanjs

I have a data as follows in which i store each date a record

```
     {
      "attendances": [
        {
          "_id": "586bb4cf5ab55f517ca4304b",
          "course": {
            "_id": "586645636ce1252f20ba1ad6",
            "name": "Robotics"
          },
          "date":"22/11/2016",
          "ispresent": "Yes",
        },
        {
          "_id": "586bafe95ab55f517ca43048",
          "course": {
            "_id": "586645636ce1252f20ba1ad6",
            "name": "Robotics"
          },
      "date":"21/11/2016",
          "ispresent": "Yes",
        },
{
          "_id": "586bafe95ab55f517ca43048",
          "course": {
            "_id": "586645636ce1252f20ba1ad6",
            "name": "Statistics"
          },
      "date":"21/11/2016",
          "ispresent": "Yes",
        },
         {
          "_id": "586bafe95ab55f517ca43048",
          "course": {
            "_id": "586645636ce1252f20ba1ad6",
            "name": "Statistics"
          },
      "date":"21/11/2016",
          "ispresent": "Yes",
        }
      ],
    }
```

I want the output as follows in a table

```
        Robotics    yes yes
        Statistics  No  yes
```

I have each record for each course with each date.Can some one help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding a groupBy filter, like the one from angular-filter lib https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter, which will group your objects based on the `name` property.

And then your html will look like something like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in attendances | groupBy: 'course.name'">
   {{key}} - <span ng-repeat="item in value">{{item.ispresent}}</span>
 </div>
```

find this working Sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/KVVK1A0QJ7VF7DbXZGi5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that the data is stored inside your controller in DATA variable.

In your template, just do:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="d in DATA">
    <td>{{d.course.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ d.ispresent ? d.ispresent : 'no'}}</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

This will display no if ispresent property doesn't exist.